# Why do you need a variogram for Kriging? goldingn/gpe package?

Tags: covariance, kriging, variogram

I am using golingn/gpe (github) package, and it does not provide a variogram and instead look at co-variances.

Is it possible to do kriging without providing variograms?

Comment: Because kriging requires values of the semivariance among all pairs of observation loctions, this question makes no sense: it's like asking whether it's possible to make apple pie without apples.  You should suspect that the "covariances" the software is using are mathematically equivalent to the information a variogram would provide :-).

Comment: Many thanks. What support or presentation can you provide to show it that 'the mathematically equivalent' is equal to Kriging.

Comment: Most kriging textbooks published in the last 30-40 years will provide a good account of the relationship.  The underlying idea is that semivariances are appropriate for "intrinsic" random fields whereas the use of covariances is limited to weakly second-order stationary fields, which is a subset of the former, but where both are applicable, they provide equivalent information and identical results.

Comment: Thank you. Do you have any references to academic papers handy?

Comment: (1) E. Isaaks and S. Srivastava, "Spatial continuity measures ..." *Math Geo.*. 20(4):313-341, 1988.  (2) A. Journel and M. Rossi, "When do we need a trend model in kriging?" *Math. Geo.* 21(7):715-739, 1989.  (3) B. Ripley, "Statistical Inference for Spatial Processes."  Cambridge U. Press, NY, 1988.  All three are referenced in (4) C. Deutsch and A. Journel, "GSLIB"  Oxford U. Press, 1992.

Comment: Thank you very much. My data consists of nearly 8000 transaction data over 18 years, so no surprise I was suggested to work with Gaussian process, which as you suggested is an approximate to simple kriging.